# Unable to run tests in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, testing, f#, functional-testing

I created a solution with 2 projects, `FSharpCalled` (which contains a method "disBonjour", transforming a string in another), an F# library,  and FSharpTest shown below :

[image]

Here's FSharpCalled :

[image: here]

The problem is that I can't run the tests; as shown in the first screenshot, I get an error message saying the "principal module is empty, so nothing will happen at execution".

I tried to modify some properties but without success.

EDIT:

here's the result... damn!

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code - post the code itself: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> principal module is empty, so nothing will happen at execution

occurs when you have a console project without an `[<EntryPoint>]`. So you'd need to either declare such a main method or change the project to be a library project.

*Update*

Do you use any 3rd party test runner (TestDriven, ReSharper with nUnit integration, ...) or the [nUnit VS Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d)? VS won't recognize nUnit tests out of the box.

Comment: ok, I've changed the type of the project (into library) but when I launch the tests VS tells me no test is found.

Comment: ok, it's changed but the error remains (tests still not found)

Comment: In my emplate project, I saw these imports : FsCheck, FsUnit, and unquote. Do you think I should use the nUnit VS test adapter? is it compatible with F# test projects? I will have a look at my side

Comment: @lolveley Yes, the test adapter is compatible with F# projects (actually with all .NET languages, it just checks the generated assemblies for tests).

Comment: Ok, it works! I installed nUnit VS test adapter from the package installer and the tests are detected; moreover in the window "test explorer" I see if the tests are a success or not. thanks to you and to Mark Seemann!

Answer (score 3):

## Classes

When you use a `let` binding inside of a *class*, the `let` binding is private (i.e. not publicly accessible). Therefore, you can't use it as a test method.

If you want to use NUnit with a class in F#, you'll have to adorn *a method* with the `[<Test>]` attribute:

```
[<TestFixture>]
type TestClass() = 
    [<Test>]
    member this.SomeTest () =
        // Test goes here
        ()
```

Last time I used NUnit, you also *had* to add the `[<TestFixture>]` attribute to the class itself, so I added that as well. Normally, I don't use NUnit, so I don't know if it's still required.

## Modules

You can also write your tests in modules, in which case you *can* adorn a `let` bound function with the `[<Test>]` attribute, since in that case it compiles to a public, static member:

```
module MyTests =
    [<Test>]
    let ``a function in a module that works as a test`` () =
        // Test goes here
        ()
```

At least, the test runner that I use ([TestDriven.net](http://testdriven.net)) discovers and runs that test as well. I don't know if all other test runners will also do that.

For a general introduction to unit testing with F#, plus much more, you may consider watching my [Pluralsight course called *Unit Testing with F#*](http://bit.ly/1JhEbA7).

Comment: I think the problem comes from the solution's structure, not from the F# test project. Indeed, the solution is build upon a C# WPF main project, on which I added a F# library (which contains the tested function), and a F# test project. Have you got an idea?

Comment: @lolveley You've declared your class inside of a module (first line). What happens if you change that to a namespace?

Comment: I get the same error (empty module => nothing will happen at the execution). The tests are not found.

Comment: @lolveley can you please produce a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: here's my code : https://www.sendspace.com/file/mh277q . it's a zip file containing the 3 VS projects : the C# one (for the GUI), the F# library one, for the work method (disBonjour) and the F# test one.

Comment: otherwise, I have an out-of-the-box issue easy to reproduce : I create a new solution with inside an F# Nunit test as the sole project; when it is created, I use NuGet to update 3 references which seem broken ( FsCheck, FsUnit and  unquote); the test file contains broken statements (call to "open FsCheck.Commands" which does not exists) but when I try to launch the remaining tests, VS tells me no test is found...

Comment: @lolveley If it doesn't compile, no tests are going to exist. You'll need to figure out why it doesn't compile.